# drupal print module pdf adding "document.write()" after content

Tags: pdf, printing, module, drupal-7

I'm using **drupal** (7) [print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module to generate **pdf** from page,

all content is generated successfully but

```
document.write("")
```

is added after,

any idea about how can i solve this **error**

Comment: your question is not clear, please explain it clearly so that others can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a view which contains list of table results,

i want to generate the pdf of that page view,

the link for pdf version (generated with print module) is present,

when i click on i get pdf version of the page view wich contains all page content

but it adds  `document.write("")` at the end

this is the screenshot of the pdf gererated :

[screenshot](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10200176186946328&set=a.10200176186706322.2199659.1201146688&type=3&src=https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/429108_10200176186946328_925952037_n.jpg&size=960,295)

Answer (score 0):

By making a simple search in my workspace I found that it was coming from the template of the print module (print.tpl.php)!

I was searching in the wrong place :(